# graphlab figures not displaying in jupyter notebooks hosted on github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, graphlab, turi

I have a notebook that uses both `matplotlib` and `graphlab` to create figures. I'm hosting this notebook on my github, and I want to display all the figures I had displayed locally. `matplotlib` figures show, but `graphlab` figures don't.

Notebook is [here](https://github.com/briennakh/coursera-machine-learning/blob/master/1.%20Machine%20learning%20foundations%20-%20A%20case%20study%20approach/Week%202/Predicting%20house%20prices.ipynb).

The code for an example figure that doesn't show:

```
import graphlab
sales = graphlab.SFrame('home_data.gl/')
graphlab.canvas.set_target('ipynb')  # set this notebook as target
sales.show(view="Scatter Plot", x="sqft_living", y="price")
```

This code is on lines 2 and 3 in my notebook. There are other figures that are not showing up as well.

How do I get these figures to show on github like they show locally?